# How to put following code in AsyncTask

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

This code is for passing values to a php page and updating a row in database
I need the following code to go in an asynctask, and how do i call it afterwards etc. I am getting the android.os.networkonmainthreadexception error.

```
    public void dbUpdate(ArrayList<NameValuePair> data, String php)
    {
    InputStream iS = null;

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(php);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        iS = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

this is code inside my button at the moment

```
public void Update(View v)
{
    try
    { 

        String nM = this.Name.getText().toString();
        String tP = this.Type.getText().toString();
        String bR = this.Breed.getText().toString();
        String gE = this.Gender.getText().toString();
        String iN = this.Injuries.getText().toString();
        String tR = this.Treat.getText().toString();

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> up = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nM));
        up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", tP));
        up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("breed", bR));
        up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", gE));
        up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("injuries", iN));
        up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("treatment", tR));

        String php = "http://select.garethprice.co.za/update.php?nM=" + nM;

        dbUpdate(up, php);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in uploading " + e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Must it be an `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Yes, HTTP requests must be executed in the background thread, otherwise they would halt all other operations in the UI thread while loading. The most straightforward method is with the AsyncTask class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this. It's a very simple implementation but it covers your situation.

```
private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
{    
     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
        try
        {
             String nM = this.Name.getText().toString();
             String tP = this.Type.getText().toString();
             String bR = this.Breed.getText().toString();
             String gE = this.Gender.getText().toString();
             String iN = this.Injuries.getText().toString(); 
             String tR = this.Treat.getText().toString(); 

             ArrayList<NameValuePair> up = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nM)); up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", tP));
             up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("breed", bR));
             up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", gE)); up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("injuries", iN));
             up.add(new BasicNameValuePair("treatment", tR)); 

             String php = "http://select.garethprice.co.za/update.php?nM=" + nM; dbUpdate(up, php); 

            dbUpdate(up, php);
        }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           Log.e("log_tag", "Error in uploading " + e.toString());
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          return false;
       }

        return true;
    }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
         if (result)
         {
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i call it then?

Comment: new YourAsyncTask().execute();

Comment: How do i make my variables global so that both my classes can use it?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/) is a good tutorial regarding AsyncTask. The calls which require connecting to backend  and fetching data  like this one

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(php);
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    iS = entity.getContent();
```

can be put in `doInBackground()` while processing of the result can be done in `PostExeceute()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like the following:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

     protected void onPreExecute() {
     }

     protected Boolean doInBackground(Void param) {
        InputStream iS = null;

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(php);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            iS = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            return false;
        }

        return true;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result)
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

`onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` will be called on the UI thread. That means it's possible to create dialogs, toasts, etc...

`doInBackground` will run on a new worker thread. This will run your network code. `doInBackground` returns a boolean to `onPostExecute` to indicate if your toast should be shown or not.

Then you run it on your button like so: `new MyAsyncTask().execute();` replacing this call: `dbUpdate(up, php);`

The official Android documentation does a good job explaining it: [Android AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

Async task is a class that can be called upon inside another to make HTTP requests in the background thread. Your AsyncTask class will be called **dbUpdate**. When you want the actions in the AsyncTask to be executed, include the following line in the appropriate method or listener.

```
new dbUpdate().execute();
```

That will be in the outer class and now we need to configure the AsyncTask class for an HTTP post request. Create a `public class dbUpdate extends AsyncTask<String, String, String, String, String, String>`. Now this class will have three methods.

```
@Override
public void onPreExecute() { super.onPreExecute(); }
protected String doInBackground(String... args) { /* more code here */ }
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result) Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Now if you want any code to be run before or after the request, include them after the super call in ***onPreExecute*** or ***onPostExecute***. In the ***doInBackground*** will be your HTTP request (the following code). You can make all the Strings global variables so they can be modified throughout both classes.

```
String nM = this.Name.getText().toString();
String tP = this.Type.getText().toString();
String bR = this.Breed.getText().toString();
String gE = this.Gender.getText().toString();
String iN = this.Injuries.getText().toString(); 
String tR = this.Treat.getText().toString();
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://select.garethprice.co.za/update.php?nM=" + nM);
try{
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", nM));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", tP));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("breed", bR));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("genders", gE));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("issues", iN));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("treatment", tR));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in uploading " + e.toString());
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
return null;
```

Comment: How do i make my variables global so that both my classes can use it?

Comment: Declare the variables outside and above both classes

Comment: If this helps you, it would be appreciated if you upvote and select a best answer